# How to set up the JsonLd @context with a custom StateProvider?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

To explain my problem, I set up a very simply ApiResource which use a custom state provider.

```php
#[ApiResource(
    types: 'https://schema.org/UpdateAction',
    provider: TransitionStateProvider::class,
)]
class Transition
{
    #[ApiProperty(
        identifier: true,
        types: ['https://schema.org/identifier'],
    )]
    public int $id;
}
```

My state provider:

```php
class TransitionStateProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        $transition = new Transition();
        $transition->id = 1;
        
        return $transition;
    }
}
```

When I send a get request, @context, @id, @types aren't set as I would like.
I got:

```json
{
    "@context": {
        "@vocab": "https://localhost/docs.jsonld#",
        "hydra": "http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#"
    },
    "@type": "Transition",
    "@id": "/.well-known/genid/66dae3d5fb3332ca13ee",
    "id": 1
}
```

What I want is:

```json
{
    "@context": "/contexts/Transition",
    "@id": "/transitions/1",
    "@type": "https://schema.org/UpdateAction",
    "id": 1
}
```

It works with my other resources, but they are linked to a doctrine entity using `stateOptions`. This `Transition` resource is not.

I tried to set up `identifier:true` in ApiProperty, I tried to play with `uriTemplate`, `urivariables` and `hydraContext` without success.

What did I miss-configure?

Comment: Can you try with it defining custom serialization groups for your entity to achieve the desired JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and create a [custom normalizer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html) to modify the serialization process and make sure the `@context`, `@id`, and `@type` are set as you wanted.

```php
namespace App\Serializer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ContextAwareNormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

class TransitionNormalizer implements ContextAwareNormalizerInterface
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function normalize($object, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);
        $data['@context'] = '/contexts/Transition';
        $data['@id'] = '/transitions/' . $object->id;
        $data['@type'] = 'https://schema.org/UpdateAction';

        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof Transition;
    }
}
```

Define the custom normalizer [as a service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-psr4-loader) and [tag it](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html) as `serializer.normalizer`. That will make sure it is registered within the [Symfony Serializer component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html).

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\Serializer\TransitionNormalizer:
        decorates: 'serializer.normalizer.object'
        tags: ['serializer.normalizer']
```

[image: https://symfony.com/doc/current/_images/components/serializer/serializer_workflow.svg]

And update the `ApiResource` [annotation](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony5/annotations) on the `Transition` class to utilize the custom normalizer.

```php
#[ApiResource(
    types: 'https://schema.org/UpdateAction',
    provider: TransitionStateProvider::class,
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['transition']]
)]
class Transition
{
    #[ApiProperty(
        identifier: true,
        types: ['https://schema.org/identifier'],
    )]
    public int $id;
}
```

You get the workflow:

```bash
+---------------+     +----------------------+     +-----------------------+     +-------------------+
| API Resource  |     | Custom Normalizer    |     |   Service Definition  |     | Desired JSON-LD   |
| Transition    | --> | TransitionNormalizer | --> | serializer.normalizer | --> |   @context Setup  |
+---------------+     +----------------------+     +-----------------------+     +-------------------+
```

Your updated code with the suggestions from above:

```php
namespace App\Serializer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ContextAwareNormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

class TransitionNormalizer implements ContextAwareNormalizerInterface
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function normalize($object, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);
        $data['@context'] = '/contexts/Transition';
        $data['@id'] = '/transitions/' . $object->id;
        $data['@type'] = 'https://schema.org/UpdateAction';

        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof Transition;
    }
}

// config/services.yaml
services:
    App\Serializer\TransitionNormalizer:
        decorates: 'serializer.normalizer.object'
        tags: ['serializer.normalizer']

// Your ApiResource and Provider remains the same
#[ApiResource(
    types: 'https://schema.org/UpdateAction',
    provider: TransitionStateProvider::class,
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['transition']]
)]
class Transition
{
    #[ApiProperty(
        identifier: true,
        types: ['https://schema.org/identifier'],
    )]
    public int $id;
}

class TransitionStateProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        $transition = new Transition();
        $transition->id = 1;
        
        return $transition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @VonC ! Your code works perfectly as I expected! I only add "Groups" on other properties, because the decorated serializer was no more displaying them. You made my day! And with your explanations, I now have a better understanding of the full workflow.

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant Great, well done!